# ordering sql select results

Tags: php, sql

i am selecting data from sql by this command:

the command can contain more then one words like

```
   select * from table where title like '%deadpool%' ////1
```

or

```
   select * from table where title like '%deadpool%' && like '%world%' ////2
```

so this show results like :

*****************1*************

1. thenewdeadpoolishere
2. deadpool

*****************2*************

1. .deadpool.world.
2. deadpool world

now, i want to order the list as follows :

*****************1*************

1. deadpool
2. thenewdeadpoolishere or whatever

*****************2*************

1. deadpool world
2. cdsghjvjdhgdeadpoolvworlddsbvs or whatever

the thing is i want to order it somehow that if the whole word of searched term is present in the result then it should show up first.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for:

```
select t.*
from table t
where title like '%deadpool%' and
      title like '%world%'
order by ((title like '%deadpool%') + (title like '%world%')) desc;
```

However, it is quite likely that you really want full text search, with order by relevancy.  You can check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) to see if this is what you really want.